# Is there a service providing historical data for crypto exchanges?

Tags: exchanges, historical-trade-data

I mean not just prices but candlestick and other data that usually is available on FX platforms?

Answer (score 1):

This is supplied by bitcoincharts.

http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/csv/

Answer (score 1):

To update this since the 3-years it was asked, there is [ClueDex](https://www.cluedex.com) that provides OHLCV candles and also raw trade data. You can get candle data for any period you wish, even non-standard periods like 15-seconds, 4-hours, 7-minutes, etc. They also have a couple of cryptocurrency market indexes based on AI that are interesting to watch when trying to figure out what to trade, if the focus of trading is making money and not losing it.